# Установка Visual Studio 2019 через корпоративный прокси

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-10, proxy

В общем, сменил ПК на работе на ПК с Windows 10 и пытаюсь поставить Visual Studio 2019.

Скачал установщик с офф. сайта и пытаюсь установить, так почему-то, когда я запускаю этот скаченный установщик, то он через какое-то время падает с ошибкой "Нет интернета", хотя он есть.

Такое впечатление, что установщик игнорит настройки прокси-сервера, которые прописал я в настройках системы(IE их тоже подхватил).

Может где-то что-то еще прописать нужно?

На Windows 7 я помню, что скачивал все без проблем.

Comment: Может лучше сначала сделать оффлайн установщик, а потом утсанавливать из папки?

Comment: @donRumata да похуже винде в каком-то месте требовалась дополнительная аутентификация... Вбивал что-то в поиск винды и тут у меня спросили учетные данные прокси(хотя я их вводил в браузере) и тут же все начало качаться...

Comment: Ну, я всё равно предпочитаю не качать ничего "на лету". В самый важный момент инет начинает или падать или тормозить. А локальный кэш всё-таки надёжней. Могу скинуть пример как раз для VS2019 как качать, а потом как ставить. На моей работе как раз нужно.

Comment: @donRumata Да я как-то давным давно качал. Просто, локальный кеш уже у меня не актуальный и вот пришлось качать все по новой.

Comment: Дык там нормальный установщик. Его запускаешь с параметром "мне нужны эти компоненты" и он сам проверяет чё обновилось, а чё нет и выкачивает только нужное.